# Creating a A/B Test in AWS with ECS Fargate and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have the following flow:

```
API Gateway --> ALB --> ECS Fargate
```

Well, I want to create a Test/AB to redirect requests to Fargate A or Fargate B, according to my query string, but my query string is dynamic, so I need a "table" to map it, for example:

Requests:

1. POST /myapi/call?region=brazil
2. POST /myapi/call?region=eua
3. POST /myapi/call?region=africa

If the query string is BRAZIL send to Fargate A, otherwise if the region is EUA send to Fargate B, and so on. I can't put static values in my ALB rules because exists a lot of countries.

Any tips how can I do it ?

Comment: You probably need something like lambda@edge

Comment: but Lambda@Edge requires a cloudfront and in my case I just  have API gateway calling ALB and after ECS Fargate.